# MVC model binding not working with @Html.RadioButtonFor() along with Enums

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enums, radio-button, model-binding

Okay. I'm getting fairly frustrated regarding this madness.

I've got a form with 4 radiobuttons, based on my custom enum.

The Enum looks like this:

```
public enum PhoneSelector
{
    PrivatePhone = 0,
    WorkPhone = 1,
    PrivateCellPhone = 2,
    WorkCellPhone = 3
}
```

The relevant part of my ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class PersonPageViewModel 
{ 
   public PersonPageForm PersonPageForm { get; set; }
}
public class PersonPageForm 
{
   public List<PhoneSelector> PhoneSelectors { get; set; }
   public PhoneSelector SelectedPhoneType { get; set; }`
}
```

The population of the viewmodel:

```
PersonPageForm = new PersonPageForm
{
    PhoneSelectors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PhoneSelector)).OfType<PhoneSelector>().ToList(),
},
```

Then in my view I've the following code: (inside `Html.BeginForm()`)

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.PersonPageForm.PhoneSelectors.Count(); i++)
{
    var currentValue = Model.PersonPageForm.PhoneSelectors[i];
    <div class="row" style="@(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userFields[i]) ? "display:none;" : string.Empty)">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PersonPageForm.SelectedPhoneType, currentValue, new {id = currentValue, Name = currentValue})
            @Html.LabelFor(x => @currentValue, Html.Translate("/radiobuttonlist/" + @currentValue) + " (" + @userFields[i] + ")", new {style = "font-weight: normal !important;"})
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And finally, the controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(PersonPageForm personPageForm, List<String> roleList, List<Int32> categoryList, String organizationType, HttpPostedFileBase userProfileImage)
```

The problem here is that everytime the submit reaches my ActionResult, `personPageForm.SelectedPhoneType` is set to `PhoneSelector.PrivatePhone`. The modelbinder doesn't seem to get what I'm trying to do here. 
Can someone provide some information regarding this solution and why it isn't working as intended.

I also tried with a simpler approach...

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PersonPageForm.SelectedPhoneType, PhoneSelector.PrivateCellPhone, new {id = Guid.NewGuid()})
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PersonPageForm.SelectedPhoneType, PhoneSelector.PrivatePhone, new { id = Guid.NewGuid() })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PersonPageForm.SelectedPhoneType, PhoneSelector.WorkCellPhone, new { id = Guid.NewGuid() })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PersonPageForm.SelectedPhoneType, PhoneSelector.WorkPhone, new { id = Guid.NewGuid() })
```

...but still ending up with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

all you need the code below ... the framework should take care of the rest for you

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PersonPageForm.SelectedPhoneType, currentValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

The model in your view is `PersonPageViewModel` and the radio buttons you generating are based on that model (i.e. they are `<input type="radio" name="PersonPageForm.SelectedPhoneType" .... />`) but the parameter in you POST method is not your model, its just some properties of your model and as a result binding fails and the value of your property is the default for your property (`PrivatePhone`).

You can solve this multiple ways. Change the POST method to accept the model your posting back

```
public ActionResult Edit(PersonPageViewModel model)
```

or use the `Prefix` property of the `[Bind]` attribute to strip the `"PersonPageForm"` prefix from the form data

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Prefix="PersonPageForm")]PersonPageForm personPageForm, List<String> roleList, ...)
```

However you over complicating this and not using a view model correctly. The `PersonPageForm` class is unnecessary and your view model should be

```
public class PersonPageViewModel
{
    public PhoneSelector SelectedPhoneType { get; set; }
}
```

and in the view

```
foreach (Enum item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(PhoneSelector)))
{
  <label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedPhoneType, item, new { id = "" })
    <span>@item</span>
  </label>
}
```